# CROSS JOIN from a parameter in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I've successfully been able to implement a `CROSS JOIN` to my query, however, I am now interested in changing the contents of the first table in the cross join to be more dynamic. So I would like to store the first table as a variable, then perform a `CROSS JOIN` between my variable table and another table.

Is there anyway to implement this behavior? How can I take a C# DataTable and put it into a table declaration in `SQL` though?

Has anyone ever tried anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a stored procedure (or more than one).

Inside a MS SQL (2005 and up, I think) stored procedure you can create a table variable like below:

```
DECLARE @tablevar table (
   ID int not null,
   Name nvarchar(100) not null,
   <rest of your columns>
)
```

In SQL 2008, you can also pass a DataTable as a parameter to an SP from .NET code.  See http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters for a good how-to (including VB.NET example code).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a DataTable to a sproc as a [Table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing you may also want to look into table-valued functions and `APPLY`